# Reward video compatible with Swift 3.0?

Tags: ios, swift, admob, rewardedvideoad

I am using Swift 3.0 and Xcode 8 Beta 6.
My app is not released on the AppStore yet.

I think I am missing something here but I don't know what. I used iAds before with other apps without any problem. But this is the first time Im trying Rewarding Videos and AdMob.

I followed your tutorial and wrote this code in my AppDelegate.swift:

```
FIRApp.configure()
GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "my_app_id_created_on_admob") 
let request = GADRequest()
GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(request, withAdUnitID: "my_add_unit_created_on_admob")
```

Then I had this in a UIViewController I am pushing when clicking on a button.

I want this VC to present the rewarding ads when it's loaded. So I also set it the AdMob delegate:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().delegate = self
}
```

I declared this VC following GADRewardBasedVideoAdDelegate as well and add all those protocol implementations at the end of the VC:

```
func rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!) {
 print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidOpen")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!) {
 print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidClose")
 GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "my_add_unit_created_on_admob")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!) {
 print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidReceive")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!) {
 print("rewardBasedVideoAdDidStartPlaying")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!) {
 print("rewardBasedVideoAdWillLeaveApplication")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!, didRewardUserWith reward: GADAdReward!) {
 print("Should reward user with \(reward.amount) \(reward.type)")
 }

 func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd: GADRewardBasedVideoAd!, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error!) {
 print("didFailToLoadWithError")
 GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().load(GADRequest(), withAdUnitID: "my_add_unit_created_on_admob")
 }
```

2 questions from there:

- Why did some videos where showing fine even if I didn't implemented any other mediation network yet on AdMob dashboard?
- Why didnt the didRewardUserWith was called after I watched the videos shown on my development device?

I was thinking that maybe it was normal, and this didRewardUserWith function would only be triggered by other mediation network advertisements. So I implemented 3 other ones (AdColony, Chartboost and AppLovin) to check if that was the reason... But then it is just HELL: no documentation up to date for those one, "adaptaters" needed but mostly not compatible with the latest AdMob framework, bridges needed from Obj-C to Swift without anyone telling it...

Other thing: since this morning, I don't really know why, my GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance() didn't succeed to load an ads video anymore...

Any help here would be veeeeeery appreciated... I'm running out of hope :(